# How to write regex pattern from my function for validation custom phone numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, validation, pcre

I have my own function to check phone number:

```
function isPhoneNumber(phone) {
    var regexForPhoneWithCountryCode = /^[0-9+]*$/;
    var regexForPhoneWithOutCountryCode = /^[0-9]*$/;
    var tajikPhone = phone.substring(0,4);
    if(tajikPhone == "+161" && phone.length !== 13) {
        return false;
    } 
    if(phone.length == 9 && phone.match(regexForPhoneWithOutCountryCode)) {
        return true;
    } else if(phone.length > 12 && phone.length < 16 && phone.match(regexForPhoneWithCountryCode)) {
        return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

My function also work, but not completely correct.

**Rules for validate phone number:**

- Max length: 13
- Min length: 9

---

When max length == 13:

- Contain only: **0-9+**
- First charackter match: **+**
- 3 charackters after "**+**" must be: **161**

---

When max length == 9:

- Contain only: **0-9**

---

**Example valid numbers:**

- +161674773312
- 674773312

Comment: You should be able to do this with one simple pattern. Try `^(?:\+161)?\d{9}$`.

Comment: A pointer that might help you out: https://regex101.com/ (flavor = javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really simple method you could use is:

```
function isPhoneNumber(phone) {
    if (phone.match(/^(?:\+161)?\d{9}$/) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```